# How do I SCP a file up to the server using the latest Ganymed SSH2 SCP Implmentation

Tags: java, ssh, scp

Recently the implementation of SCP changed within the Ganymed SSH2 library. I'm struggling to figure out how to push a file up to the server. The SCPOutputStream class doesn't seem to accept an actual file just a file name and remote path. Can someone help me understand how I would implement this to push a file? Please note I am using the most recent build of Ganymede.

Thank you!

https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPClient.java

https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPOutputStream.java

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of it as copying a local file to the remote system. Think of it as writing a file on the remote system, with contents that may or may not have come from a local file.

[`SCPClient.put()`](https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPClient.java#178) starts the process of writing a file to the remote system. You specify the name of the remote file, the remote directory to put it in, the file size, and the file's mode (permissions). All of these things are required by the SCP protocol.

[`SCPOutputStream`](https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/ethz/ssh2/SCPOutputStream.java) is the object that you use to write to the remote file. Anything written to the stream is sent to the remote system and saved in the remote file. Close the stream when you're finished writing to it.

To copy a local file to the remote system, you'd get the local file's name and size, and figure out what mode you want (You could use 0644 or 0666 for the mode). Then call `SCPClient.put()` to begin writing to the remote file. `SCPClient.put()` returns an `SCPOutputStream`. You would open the local file for reading and copy its contents to the `SCPOutputStream`. Close the `SCPOutputStream` and the stream that you used to read from the local file when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Too late probably to be really useful to the original OP, but I recently solved the exact same issue. I also struggled because the tutorials/examples show solutions for a different implementation.

The thing is, the method scpclient.put doesnt actually put the file anywhere, it just opens a special outputstream on the remote server which you need to feed the original local file into, and then close everything.

Here is my Scala solution (can turn to Java mostly by putting semicolons and types), hopefully it can help someone.

So, first of all, my SSHUtils class which is a wrapper:

```
package foo
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler
import ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient
import ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPOutputStream

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

case class ConnectionInfo(username:String, password:String,     hostname:String, port:Int)

object SSHUtils {

  def scp(src:String, size:Long, targetName:String,targetDir:String, ci:ConnectionInfo) : Unit = {
    val conn = connect(ci)
    val cli :SCPClient = conn.createSCPClient().asInstanceOf[SCPClient]
    val out :SCPOutputStream = cli.put(targetName, size, targetDir,"0644")
    val in = new  FileInputStream(new File(src))
    IOUtils.copy(in, out)
    in.close()
    out.close()
    conn.close()
  }

  def connect(ci: ConnectionInfo):Connection = {

    val conn = new Connection(ci.hostname, ci.port)
    conn.connect()
    val isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(ci.username, ci.password)
    if (isAuthenticated == false)
      throw new IOException("Authentication failed.")
    conn
  }
}
```

and then, how I can copy a small txt file to the remote host (at directory "./") from my scala console:

```
import foo.SSHUtils
import foo.ConnectionInfo
import java.io.File

val ci : ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(dc_username, dc_password, dc_host, dc_port)

val f = new File("/home/carolinux/qgis.txt")

SSHUtils.scp(f.toString, f.length,f.getName, "./", ci)
```

I needed, in addition to the Ganymede library to also use commons.io to have a nice way to write the local file into the scpoutputstream. The sbt dependencies are:

```
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
"ch.ethz.ganymed" % "ganymed-ssh2" % "262" // the latest one in maven at the time of writing
```